# Powershell error Cannot convert the System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManage

Tags: xml, powershell

I`m tryng to create a new xml with part of another absolete xml file.

```
     $xml = New-Object XML
     $dec = $xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8","yes")
     $xml.AppendChild($dec)
     $root = $xml.CreateElement("Remove")
     $xml.AppendChild($root)
     $xml.load('C:\Source\Fakamae_2018005_KM.xml')

     $namespaceMgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
     $namespace = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
     $namespaceMgr.AddNamespace("Opex", $namespace)



     $Meta= Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '/Opex:OpexMatadata' -Namespace $namespaceMgr
     $doc = [Xml](gc 'c:\\Source\Fakamae_2018005_KM.xml')
     $imported=$xml.ImportNode($doc.OPEXMetadata.DescriptiveMetadata.METATRANSCRIPT,$true)
     $Meta.Node.AppendChild($imported)
     $xml.Save('c:\\Source\Output\Result.xml')
```

But in this line:

```
     $Meta= Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//Opex:OpexMatadata' -Namespace $namespaceMgr
```

Returns this error:

Select-Xml : Cannot bind parameter 'Namespace'. Cannot convert the "System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager" value of type "System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".

What i`m doing wrong, and how cam i solve this?
Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Thanks for your feedback AdminOfthings, but i still get the same massage . :(

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7) explain that namespace must be a hash table, not a namespace object.